# square root of sum of square of columns in multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I am using multidimensional list with numpy

I have a list.

```
l = [[0 2 8] [0 2 7] [0 2 5] [2 4 5] [ 8 4 7]]
```

I need to find square root of sum of square of columns.

```
0 2 8
0 2 7
0 2 5
2 4 5
8 4 7
```

output as,

```
l = [sqrt((square(0) + square(0) + square(0) + square(2) + square(8))  sqrt((square(2) + square(2) + square(2) + square(4) + square(4)) sqrt((square(8) + square(7) + square(5)) + square(5) + square(7))]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[0, 2, 8], [0, 2, 7], [0, 2, 5], [2, 4, 5], [ 8, 4, 7]])
>>> np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(a), axis=0))
array([  8.24621125,   6.63324958,  14.56021978])
```

Comment: I think the inner sqrt should be a square

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary : sorry mistaken in writting question. I have updated question.

Answer (score 4):

Use the standard function [numpy.linalg.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) for this...

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 2, 8], [0, 2, 7], [0, 2, 5], [2, 4, 5], [ 8, 4, 7]])
np.linalg.norm(a,axis=0)
```

gives:

`array([ 8.24621125,  6.63324958, 14.56021978])`

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.sum(np.array(l)**2,axis=0)**.5
array([ 10.67707825,   3.46410162,  11.74734012])
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is use map/reduce

In theory in can be done using nested for loops but could be done in a more functional way...

```
for l in matrix:
    sum all elements**2 in 
    return the squar root of the sum
```

A one liner:

```
map(lambda x: sqrt(lambda r, z: r + z**2, x), matrix)
```

But to make it more clear, you could rewrite it as such:

```
def SumOfSquare(lst):
    return reduce(lambda r, x: r + x**2, lst)

def ListOfRoot(lst):
    return map(lambda x: SumOfSquare(x), lst)

s = ListOfRoot(matrix)
```

Misread the question, it's without numpy.